# Sigma fields for the rolling of two dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am required to find three distinct sigma fields $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2,\Sigma_3$ such that $\emptyset \neq \Sigma_1 \subset \Sigma_2 \subset \Sigma_3 \neq \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space for an experiment where two dice are rolled. The ones I have chosen are $\{\emptyset,\Omega\} \subset \{\emptyset,\Omega, \{(1,1)\},\{(1,1)\}^{c}\} \subset P(\Omega)$, where $P(\Omega)$ is the power set of $\Omega$. Would this be fine? I am only a beginner in this area.

Comment: Are $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$, $\Sigma_3$ supposed to be subsets of $\Omega$? You haven't stated that, but otherwise $\Omega$ doesn't have much to do with the problem.

Comment: Instead of $\emptyset \neq \Sigma_1 \subset \Sigma_2 \subset \Sigma_3 \neq \Omega$, maybe you meant $\{\emptyset,\Omega\} \neq \Sigma_1 \subset \Sigma_2 \subset \Sigma_3 \neq P(\Omega)$?

Comment: That's what threw me, but that is exactly as it was stated in the problem.

Comment: Because on their own, the sample space and empty set aren't sigma fields anyway, so I can't understand why that info was included